# How do I change react-script auto generated imports?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I have a react application, which was created using create-react-app. I included react-bootstrap in my project and when I start/build application, bootstrap css file imported. How can I change this css with my custom one? 
I am aware that I can just add new css in index.js, but won't both css files be imported in that case?

Since I am creating a custom bootstrap theme, I would prefer if default bootstrap css file is not imported, as I am building new css file from my custom scss file and bootstrap scss files.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reading-manager-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

npm start generates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

How do I go about changing these imports to my own compiled ones? I would prefer not to use remote repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that `npm start` will generate `<link>` tags because `react-scripts` doesn't contain a mechanism to inject them and resolve packages to CDN URLs automatically.

`create-react-app` configures Webpack to support CSS loaders, the boilerplate already contains:

```
import './App.css';
```

Any CSS can be imported like that:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: What do you mean unlikely? Nowhere in my application I have added CDN imports for bootstrap, yet after I start application with `npm start`, they are added.

Comment: I think react-bootstrap is adding those imports.

Comment: react-bootstrap doesn't add Bootstrap styles automatically. Neither react-scripts, nor bootstrap, nor react-bootstrap are able to do `bootstrap` to `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap...` replacement, and there's to place for them to get CDN URL automatically, as far as I know. I would expect that these CDN styles were added somehow in project index.html or .css. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - a repo or so. I'd suggest to search for `bootstrapcdn` string in your project folder first.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, you were correct, imports were added manually in index.html (didn't check public folder).

Comment: @CrazySabbath Glad you sorted this out. I started to think I'm missing something important about Webpack configuration in CRA.